# When to use Perfekt and Präteritum?

Tags: tense, perfect-tense, preterite

What’s the guideline as to **when to use Perfekt and Präteritum**?

I was always taught that the simplest rule is *Präteritum* (mostly) for written forms, and *Perfekt* is most common in spoken language.

But I’ve also come across explanations paying more attention to the context – comparing *Präteritum* to the French *Imparfait* (narrative past, little to no influence on current events). That way *Perfekt* would be mostly used for completed events with present results.

How do you combine those two approaches? Which tense to choose so as not to sound weird in a native context?

For example, would

> Ich kaufte einen Computer.

really be the preferred form in writing over the following?

> Ich habe einen Computer gekauft.

Comment: very good question! I think this is one of the most difficult parts when you're learning a new language, because it seems natural for native speakers but very hard to distinguish for people who are still learning.

Comment: Although there are dialects that use Perfekt a lot where Hochdeutsch uses Präteritum, it's definitely not true that Präteritum is for written and Perfekt is for spoken.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You use Präteritum for events which are not yet completed or for which the time doesn’t matter. In novels for example Präteritum is used more often.

There is a really good article in German on this topic: [Präteritum oder Perfekt?](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/prateritum-imperfekt-perfekt.php)

Comment: +1 for the article. Although it says "Präteritum (Im­per­fekt)" in the title and later "Das deutsche Prä­te­ri­tum ist jedoch kein Imperfekt."

Comment: What you're writing is true for the _written_ language. When _speaking_ German, you'll hardly ever use Präteritum. (That's mostly reserved for auxiliary and modal verbs.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Well, it depends a lot on where you live.

Comment: The answer is in contradiction to what is said in the linked article. Whether Perfekt or Präteritum is used depends more on whether the sentence is spoken or written than on when the action is completed. This is quite different from other European languages which may confuse non-native speakers.

Answer (score 17):

As a general note because people tend to confuse this:
Obviously, many written texts use the *Präteritum*, even though one gets the impression that it is scarcely used in everyday life. Now, this does not imply that *Präteritum* is the past tense used in written form whereas *Perfekt* is the kind of informal spoken form of it. Nor does it mean that one needs to convert a spoken *Perfekt* to *Präteritum* when writing it or use *Perfect* when re-telling a scary novel at a campfire.

Obviously, there is a point to it or people wouldn’t notice. However, it is of course not that  *Präteritum* was so complicated that it could only be used at a desk with one hand in the conjugation table.

The reason is that the form and intention of texts which are written down and texts which are spoken differs:
*Präteritum* is the way of telling a story. Therefore, it is also used when *writing* a story. A story in that sense is anything which is *remote*. It may be in the past, it may be in the future, it may just not be of primary concern for the person who tells it.

*Perfekt* is the way of discussing something which happened in the past and is of primary and immediate relevance for the person who tells it. So, when a friend asks, why you look so happy and whether any of the events the other day are related to that, you may very well use *Perfekt* tense because it is not remote to you or him/her.

---

As an interesting read, I may suggest the book ‘[Tempus: Besprochene und erzählte Welt](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/340647876X)’ written by Harald Weinrich which explains this difference for various European languages. (I think the [belleslettres article](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/prateritum-imperfekt-perfekt.php) makes similar arguments but I haven’t had the time to fully read it.)

Answer (score 12):

> Ich kaufte einen Computer

sounds wrong to me even in written form. Perhaps it would be okay if you're writing a novel and were describing the circumstances of buying a computer. But in a normal sentence I'd prefer

> Ich habe einen Computer gekauft.

While:

> Das Wetter war schön am Dienstag. Ich lag den ganzen Tag in der Sonne.

is perfectly right. In German the "Präteritum" is also called the "Erzählzeit" ("narrative tense").

I think that Perfect has become the dominant form when describing the past. You almost can't be wrong if you're using it.

Comment: But why? I completely agree but I can't explain it. Does it have to do with duration?

Comment: Im einfachen Präteritum wird - umgangssprachlich! - der Verlauf  betont. *"Ich lag in der Sonne"* bezieht sich auch einen Zeitraum. Nur, wenn ein *", als folgendes passierte: …"* hinzukommt, reduziert sich die Bedeutung wieder auf einen Zeitpunkt. Deshalb ist *"ich kaufte einen Computer"* zwar grammatikalisch korrekt, die Semantik aber stimmt nicht.

Comment: @Tomalak Es könnte aber auch richtig sein. Zum Bleistift: "Ich kaufte gerade einen Computer, als mir Stefan, der Apple-Fanboy, ein iPad andrehen wollte." ;)

Comment: -1, wenn ich könnte, für "zum Bleistift". ;) - Hier käme die rheinische Verlaufsform gelegen: *"Ich war gerade am Computer kaufen, als…"*.

Comment: The example was purposely exaggerated to comment on the spoken/written rule, but it is like @musiKk said - at times it's only a gut feeling of something sounding right or not. I would probably find it hard to explain to someone else though, which I assume would mean that deep down I don't really know the difference that well.

Answer (score 11):

For the *spoken* language, a good guideline is indeed to use the Perfekt, except for auxiliary and modal verbs and a few other very common verbs (can't say which ones, unfortunately). To expand on the example in splattne's answer (I *wouldn't* say "Ich lag den ganzen Tag in der Sonne", and sorry, I'm a bad narrator):

> Das Wetter *war* schön am Dienstag. Ich *habe* den ganzen Tag in der Sonne *gelegen*. Obwohl ich eigentlich nichts essen *wollte*, *habe* ich mir drei Kugeln Eis *geholt* – leider *gab* nur Erdbeer und Vanille. Ich *wusste* gar nicht mehr, wie gut das schmeckt. Am Nachmittag *haben* mich noch ein paar Freunde *besucht*.

Comment: +1 Your answer is very close to what I am looking for. Could you please check my quesion [Usage of Perfekt and Präteritum in the spoken language](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5055/1509) ?

Comment: @Ali: You asked a really good question there. I think I can't give a better answer than Emanuel.

Comment: Or in the case of a Bavarian: *ich **bin** den ganzen Tag in der Sonne gelegen* ;)

Answer (score 1):

In general both forms are used to describe what happened in the past. Usually in spoken language there is no differentiation between Präteritum and Perfekt. Präteritum sounds more formal whereas Perfekt is commonly used and sounds more familiar.

typical perfect in spoken language: "Ich habe das Bad geputzt und danach die Wäsche gewaschen."

In a newspaper or more formal reports Präteritum is used: "Der Präsident begrüßte die Besucher."

There are cases of mandatory Präteritum and mandatory Perfekt. The latter is used when something happened and was finished in the past but is still effective.

some good examples are found here: http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/verbformen/der-gebrauch-der-tempora-zeiten/gebrauch-praeteritum-perfekt/

Perfekt is - unlike Präteritum - a combined time (time of observation and time of reporting) and is interpreted in two steps. Also see: http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/gruwi.ansicht?v_typ=p&v_id=4808

Comment: Das einzige, das vielleicht noch nicht in den anderen Antworten war, ist hinter den Links versteckt. Lohnt es sich, das zusammenzufassen?

Comment: Ja, ich hatte das im Sinn, wollte allerdings nicht alles ins Englische übersetzen. Meinst du copy'n'paste mit Angabe der Herkunft würde es tun?

Comment: Vielleicht noch ein paar "Regeln" aus meiner Schulzeit, als wir die Zeitformen in 'zig Fremdsprachen bis zum Erbrechen durchgingen und miteinander verglichen. Präteritum beschreibt Situationen, (abgelaufene) Handlungen, Personen, Charaktereigenschaften und Gegenstände in der Vergangenheit. Perfekt drückt aus, dass eine Handlung in der Vergangenheit abgeschlossen wurde und die Folge der Handlung im Vordergrund steht. Plusquamperfekt beschreibt Handlungen, die zeitlich vor einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt in der Vergangenheit stattfanden. In Schriftform wird das noch unterschieden, im Gespräch nicht.

Comment: Die Antwort ist richtig und sagt das, was im Grammatikbuch steht. Nur entspricht das leider einfach nicht dem praktischen Sprachgebrauch. Wenn ich Perfekt verwende, überlege ich mir nicht erst, ob das, was da passiert ist, sich auch auf die Gegenwart noch auswirkt oder nicht.....