# Wann wird Präteritum in Bayern verwendet?

Tags: dialect, bavarian, preterite

Ich habe gehört, dass das Präteritum in Bayern sehr unüblich ist. Wann wird es da verwendet?

Ich meine hier den Bairisch-beeinflussten deutschen Dialekt, der in Bayern gesprochen wird.

Comment: Keine direkte Antwort auf deine Frage, daher nur der Kommentar: in Baden-Württemberg wird das Präteritum eigentlich nur bei *sein* verwendet (Ich war früher Lehrer), sonst findet man in der gesprochenen Sprache nur das Perfekt, das Präteritum klingt hochgestochen. In Bayern wird es ähndlich sein, aber da ich nicht von dort komme, überlasse ich die Antwort lieber jemandem, der sich auskennt.

Comment: Wie ist die Frage zu verstehen? In Bayern insbesondere in München leben auch viele Menschen die arbeitsbedingt hinzugezogen sind und gar kein richtiges Bairisch verstehen gescheige denn sprechen können. Ist hier der Gebrauch im Bairischen oder der allgemeine Gebrauch in Bayern gemeint. Aus dem Zusammenhang gerissen würde ich die Frage in letzterem Sinne verstehen.

Comment: @bernd_k: Ich habe die Frage aufgeklärt. Ist es deutlicher?

Comment: Ich bin mir nicht ganz sicher, wie weit das noch ein Dialekt ist. Durch die Zuwanderer aus anderen Teilen Deutschlands und die Einflüsse der Schule auf die Kinder findet eine Veränderung auch bei den Einheimischen statt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**

*Wenn du Bayern als Gebiet meinst und nicht die bayrischen Dialekte:* Die Verwendung/Nicht-Verwendung des Präteritums hängt wohl stark davon ab, ob jemand den bayrischen Dialekt spricht (wie es in ländlichen Gegenden üblich ist) oder nicht (*"[Zuagroasde](http://www.fr-online.de/digital/bayrisch-fuer--zuagroasde-/-/1472406/3200270/-/index.html)"*). Die des Bayrisch Mächtigen werden das Präteritum aus Gewohnheit oder instinktiv auch in der Hochsprache vermeiden.

Auch nach Bayern zugewanderte Menschen verwenden vermehrt das Perfekt als bevorzugte Vergangenheitsform; nicht zuletzt deshalb, weil das Präteritum im Deutschen allgemein immer weniger verwendet wird (der so genannte *"Präteritumschwund"*).

---

Auf dieser [Seite über die Grammatik des Bayrischen](http://www.bayrisch-lernen.de/grammatik/grammatik.html) wird erklärt, dass es im Bayrischen **kein Präteritum für Vollverben** wie im Hochdeutschen gibt:

> Alle TAM-Formen [Tense - Aspect - Mode] außer Präsens und Konditional werden durch Zuhilfenahme eines Auxiliar- oder Modularverbes gebildet, nämlich 'sai', 'hom', 'doà', 'weàn'.

**Hilfs- und Umstandsverben** werden ähnlich den deutschen Verbformen gebildet (die mit * markierten Formen *existieren nicht*):

```
Verb   Perfekt                   Präteritum
------ ------------------------- -------------------
woin   i hob ned dringa woin     i woid ned dringa
soin   i hob ned dringa soin     i soid ned dringa
miàsn  i hob ned dringa miàsn    *i muàsd ned dringa
deàfa  i hob ned dringa deàfa    *i duàfd ned dringa
kenna  i hob ned dringa kenna    *i kond ned dringa

Verb   Perfekt                   Präteritum
------ ------------------------- -------------------
ham    i hob's ned gheàd         *i heàd's ned
sai    i bin's ned gwen          i wa's ned
doa    i hob's ned doa           *i dad's ned
wean   i bin's ned woan          *i wuad's ned
```

---

Wer sich für die bayrische Dialekte interessiert, findet übrigens auf folgender Website den Spachlehrgang *"[Redmaaweng Boarisch](http://www.bairische-sprache.at/Raamaremarawengboarisch.html)"*  *("Reden wir ein wenig Bayrisch")*

Comment: Jeeperzzzzzzz!!

Comment: Vielleicht war meine Frage nicht so deutlich -- ich fragte (habe gefragt?) über Deutsch in Bayern, nicht Bayrisch :)

Comment: Das hängt glaub ich ganz stark damit zusammen, ob du "Preußen" in Bayern meinst, oder "Eingeborene" ;) - die Leute mit dialektalem Hintergrund werden das Präteritum instinktiv vermeiden.

Comment: @splaattne: Wir "Preußen", die in München arbeiten, zum Teil auch. Ich glaube auch, dass man sich in diesem Bereich nach ein paar Jahren leicht an sein Umfeld anpasst.

Comment: Danke!

Comment: Kann ich als geborener Bayer nur bestätigen, für uns ist diese Zeitform einfach nicht existent. Und wenn jemand das Präteritum verwendet wird er direkt als Auswärtiger abgestempelt.

Answer (score 7):

**Vorab**

Die Frage wurde vor langer Zeit gestellt, aber ich fand die bisherigen Antworten nicht zufriedenstellend / nicht akkurat im Bezug auf den tatsächlichen, mündlichen Sprachgebrauch. Ich bin Deutsch-Muttersprachler mit gemischter süddeutscher Prägung (Bayern / Österreich) und beziehe mich in meiner Antwort auf alltägliches "Hochdeutsch" / Standarddeutsch, wie es in Bayern und vor allem München gesprochen wird.

Ich habe die Fragen [When to use Perfekt and Präteritum?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-to-use-perfekt-and-pr%C3%A4teritum), [Usage of Perfekt and Präteritum in the spoken language](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5055/usage-of-perfekt-and-pr%C3%A4teritum-in-the-spoken-language), [Warum Perfekt anstelle von Präteritum und seit wann?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/warum-perfekt-anstelle-von-pr%C3%A4teritum-und-seit-wann), [Präteritum of “sein” in Southern dialects](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7050/pr%C3%A4teritum-of-sein-in-southern-dialects) gelesen und den Eindruck, dass in keiner der Fragen eine ausreichend einfache und in der Praxis anwendbare Antwort gegeben wird. Im Übrigen scheint mir diese Fragen in jedem Gebiet in Deutschland eine andere Antwort zu verlangen. Eine Antwort für alle Varianten des Deutschen erscheint mir unmöglich.

Der Artikel [Präteritum oder Perfekt](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/prateritum-imperfekt-perfekt.php) von Belles Lettres ist eine empfehlenswerte und ausführliche Darstellung, bringt es aber nicht auf den Punkt und entspricht für mein Empfinden nicht (vollständig) dem Sprachgebrauch des Hochdeutschen in Bayern.

**Zum Thema**

Das Präteritum ist im Allgemeinen in Bayern durch das Perfekt in der üblichen täglichen Rede ersetzt worden. Generell wirkt die Verwendung des Präteritums, insbesondere im in Bayern gesprochenen Hochdeutsch unüblich. Einen Zusammenhang zu der Abgeschlossenheit, Dauer, Modus der Handlung etc. wie beispielsweise im Englischen oder Französischen sehe ich nicht.

Es gibt ein paar Ausnahmen, wo die Verwendung des Präteritums noch üblich **und bevorzugt** ist:

- Das Verb sein: "Gestern war ich sehr müde" ist üblicher als "gestern bin ich sehr müde gewesen". Beide sind in Bayern zulässig.
- Beim literarischen Erzählen: wenn man eine Geschichte erzählt und möchte, dass diese nicht alltäglich, sondern besonders klingt.
- Bestimmte andere Verben in der Funktion als Vollverb stehen häufig im Präteritum, wenn die Handlung in der Vergangenheit war: finden, wollen, dürfen, können.

**Mögliche Ursachen**

Ich sehe den Grund für diese sprachliche Wandlung darin, dass die Präteritumsformen jenseits der Präteritalgrenze von den Sprechern als zu schwierig zu bilden bewertet werden:

- Das liegt zum einen an der vergleichsweise starken Flexion von Präteritumsformen im Vergleich zum regelmäßiger gebildeten Perfekt. Siehe dazu den [Trend zum analytischen Sprachbau](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Synthetischer_Sprachbau&oldid=131411190#Zur_Entwicklung_und_Stellung_des_Deutschen).
- Einige lautliche Kombinationen von Nukleus-Vokalen und darauf folgenden Konsonanten der konjugierten Präteritumsformen könnten ebenfalls als "unangenehm" vom süddeutschen/bayerischen Sprecher empfunden werden. Beispiel: r*och*, spr*ach*, br*ach* sind alle in Bayern quasi nicht benutzte Präteritumsformen im alltäglichen Gebrauch und werden durch das Perfekt ersetzt. Das Phänomen der Apokope wie [in dieser Antwort erklärt](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7323/8823), deutet in dieselbe Richtung, beschreibt aber eine andere lautliche Veränderung.

Comment: +1. Allerdings halte ich *finden, dürfen* und *können* für nichtverwendete Präteritumsformen, zumindest im südlichen Oberbayern.