# Exact meaning of present perfect in German

Tags: past-participle, perfect-tense

In English **present perfect** is used to show that something happened in the past which has an effect that still remains till now (**present**).

[image]

Now let's take a look at a simple **Present Perfekt** sentence in German.

> Wir haben schwer gearbeitet.

As far as I know, it must be translated as "We have worked hard". Meanwhile it is translated "We worked hard.", which means it is in **simple past** tense!

These examples confuse me. I don't know **when** I can use **Present Perfekt**?

Is the German Present Perfekt both English Simple Past and Present Perfect?

Comment: Are you interested in literary or colloquial language?

Comment: I like colloquial language

Comment: Related:  http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5055/usage-of-perfekt-and-präteritum-in-the-spoken-language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usage of tenses in English and German is different, so while the English present perfect tense and the German *Perfekt* are formed in a very similar manner, you should not equate them.

Generally, the German *Perfekt* and *Präteritum* (or whatever you like to call them) express the same thing, using one or the other does not express a difference in meaning. So when translating from German you should just see them as “some kind of past tense” and then choose an appropriate tense in the target language by context.

The other way around, which of those two German tenses is used is a bit more difficult. It will indeed depend on the register and the speaker (there are differences between Northern and Southern Germany). You should be aware however, that both tenses are often mixed and which is chosen depends on the verb and does not differentiate in meaning. For example

> Ich war im Büro und habe an dem Vortrag gearbeitet.

would be perfectly valid.

Comment: While in general there is no semantic difference between the perfect and the preterite a speaker **can** use the perfect to give a statement a more "perfective" (or rather "resultative") meaning. E.g. "Ich habe die Tür zugemacht" emphasizing that the door is now closed, not the action of closing the door. But the perfect doesn't have to have this meaning, it can simply replace the preterite. As a general rule, in spoken German the perfect is preferred, whereas in written German the preterite is preferred. When telling a story from the past the preterite is the usual tense (_Erzähltempus_).