# Which verbs use the Präteritum in spoken language(Northern Germany)?

Tags: modal-verb, perfect-tense, preterite, spoken-language

I would like to know which verbs(besides sein, haben, and the modals) are commonly spoken in the Präteritum in Northern Germany, specifically Berlin(state).

This question was answered partially [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/5060/20008) but the answers were not region specific. According to the linked answer, the following (non sein/haben/modal)verbs are commonly spoken in the Präteritum in unspecified parts of Germany(specific use cases are explained in the link):

- gehen
- finden
- aussehen
- geben
- liegen (used more often than *gelegen*)
- stehen
- rufen
- denken
- tun (not used often in any tense outside of *tut mir leid*)
- übrig bleiben

I know that *wissen* is sometimes used as well, is there a guideline for this?
Any suggested changes to this list?

Comment: We must separate between senses of every such verb, as with *tun* and *bleiben*.  *finden* in *Ich fand's gut* is different than *Hast Du den Schlüssel gefunden?*  Then you will see that, although it is not completely logic-driven, there is a tendency to use the preterite for ongoing states, similar to imperfect.  In that sense, it is not an arbitrary function of the verb, but rather of intended meaning.  That said, there is often overlap in meaning, and differences between regions and registers.

Comment: Spoken language is regionally different - Swiss german and some south-western dialects don't even *know* the Präteritum. So, good you asked for a region.

Comment: I'm not sure, how you arrived at the conclusion, that *tun* is rarely used; in any case I disagree, especially in spoken language and even more so when a limited vocabulary is an issue.

Comment: As I understand SO, breathing new air into an existing question is typically done by setting a bounty, which avoids the danger of the question being closed as duplicate.

Comment: I doubt there ever will be a concise list of verbs - as said in the linked Q&A it is regionally **very** different. People have their preferences but they still may use one or the other tense in spoken German everywhere. Both are allowed and both are prefectly understood. Please **[edit]** your question to better clarify where your question is different to the duplicate question, and which of your concerns were not answered there.

Comment: @Takkat I have edited the question, can it be reopened?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Your question in now in the reopen review queue. It will be reopened on sufficient votes from the community.

Comment: @tofro Even for *sein*? (Bavarian knows exactly two preterites: *war* and *wollt*)