# “Ja, das dachte ich mir.” – Why “mir”?

Tags: pronoun, grammar-identification

I saw this exchange on Twitter:

> »Was denkst du gerade?«
>   »nichts!«
>   »Ja, das dachte ich mir.«

Why is *mir* in this sentence? It seems redundant.  I assume it is one of the rules of grammar.

Comment: Vermutlich die Unterdchied zwischen dem Beispielsatz und dem Satz ohne "mir" wäre hier wichtig. Erkläre nicht die Bedeutung, sonst *die Unterschied*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mir** is the dative of **sich**, and the phrase used is *es sich denken*.

> Er brachte Blumen mit. Sie dachte sich schon, dass etwas nicht stimmte.

*He brought flowers. She thought to herself something was fishy.*

Comment: *Mir* is the dative of *ich,* which is required because *sich etwas denken* is reflexive. *Mir* is the first person singular form of *sich.*

Comment: Haha what an unfortunate sample sentence in a sense. I can only think maybe he's an assassin or something. Also, in reflexive form with dative, I think "denken" means "imagine", "guess" etc., not exactly "think" as its original non-reflexive form.

Comment: @Ji Xiang: That's a perfectly normal sentence you would read in a romance novel or similar. No assasins needed. The thing which *nicht stimmte* is he had to excuse himself by bringing flowers for a fauxpas he made - which she don't know exactly. The OP asked exactly about the difference between *denken* and *sich denken* and the example is deliberately chosen for that reason. Because in English you could also use a reflexive construction instead of changing the verb to *imagine* or *guess*.

Answer (score 3):

The verb in question is [*sich etwas denken*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/denken#wb-1), meaning a) sub-meaning at the downwards-pointing arrow. In this context, it means *to guess something.*

Since the verb is reflexive, it requires a reflexive pronoun. And since there is also an accusative object *(etwas),* the reflexive pronoun in the first and second person forms defaults back to the dative object pronoun. Thus, it must be:

> Ich habe mir das gedacht.
>   Du hast dir das gedacht.
>   Sie hat sich das gedacht.
>   Wir haben uns das gedacht.
>   Ihr habt euch das gedacht.
>   Sie haben sich das gedacht.

(Side note: I used the perfect form instead of preterite here which is [more natural to me as a Bavarian](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/28479) since the dialog is closer to informal, spoken than to formal, written language.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the important point to be emphasized here is that there are different versions of the word "denken", one of which is reflexive and requires a dative pronoun. Its meaning can be said as "imagine", not exactly the original "think" which is the version without reflexive and dative requirement.

For reference see for example https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/denken