# What is the purpose of "ihm" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Was bedeutet ihm Sexualität mit Ihnen?

[Google](https://translate.google.de/m/translate?hl=de) translates this as

> What does sexuality mean to you?

but it skips the meaning of *"ihm"*.

I have an idea that this sentence means something like

> To him, what does sexuality mean with them?

What do you think?

Sentence is taken from the article [Wie kann ich meinen Freund zu einem Dreier überreden?](https://www.zeit.de/zeit-magazin/leben/2018-06/sex-zu-dritt-dreier-paarbeziehung-sexuelle-fantasie) in the Zeit magazine.

Comment: Other questions dealing with dativus commodi: [Usage concerning “mir/mich”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39629/usage-concerning-mir-mich), [Understanding “ihm” in “so fiel ihm das Herz doch eine Elle tiefer herab”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30944/understanding-ihm-in-so-fiel-ihm-das-herz-doch-eine-elle-tiefer-herab), [An ambiguous pronoun](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44562/an-ambiguous-pronoun), [“Ja, das dachte ich mir.” – Why “mir”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33651/ja-das-dachte-ich-mir-why-mir) and many others

Comment: Your idea is good, however the third person plural is used as polite address (as indicated by the capitalisation), so it should be *you* instead of *them*. And in English, *with you* then maybe wants to be nearer to *sexuality*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Was bedeutet ihm Sexualität mit Ihnen?

*What does (having) sex with you mean to him?*.

> Was – *subject*
>
> bedeutet – *predicate*
>
> ihm – *dative object*
>
> Sexualität – *predicative (nominative object)*
>
> mit Ihnen – *prepositional object: mit+dative*

Google translate stumbled across the two datives, it does not know about prepositions which take the dative, it seems. You stumbled across *Ihnen*, which is a formal *you*, not *them*. You can tell by the caps **I**.

Comment: The problem (not with your answer, but with the original sentence) is that Sexualität does not mean Geschlechtsverkehr, nor does sexuality mean sexual intercourse.

Comment: It's an euphemism, and often used this way.

Comment: I would call it a barbarism, but maybe I have read too much Foucault.