# Das Präteritum vs Perfekt bei der mündlichen Alltagssprache

Tags: perfect-tense, preterite, speaking

Zwei Lehrer haben mir gesagt, dass ich beim Sprechen zu oft das Präteritum benutze, und, dass ich eher das Perfekt benutzen sollte.  Und zwar, dass man kaum das Präteritum beim Sprechen benutzt, außer bei Modalverben, Passiv, z.B..  Ich habe das angenommen, aber ich habe viele Podcasts angehört, in denen das Präteritum beim Sprechen benutzt wurde, z.B.

> Wo saßt Ihr?

Wie benutzt man das Präteritum bzw. das Perfekt in der Alltagssprache am besten, und soll man beim alltäglichen Sprechen versuchen, das Präteritum sooft zu vermeiden, wie möglich ist?

Wenn diese eine zu unklare/unscharfe Frage ist, oder ein zu breites Thema ist, um eine klare Antwort zu geben, würde ich trotzdem gerne irgendwelche allgemeine Hinweise zum Thema bekommen. Ich habe [dieses ziemlich lange Video](https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/verb/tempus-aspekt-prateritum-perfekt.php) gefunden, das zwar sehr interesant scheint, aber ich weiß nicht, ob es meine praktische Fragen beantworten würde.

Comment: Gleiche Frage in Englisch: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5055/usage-of-perfekt-and-pr%c3%a4teritum-in-the-spoken-language

Comment: Es wäre interessant zu wissen wo deine Lehrer herkommen und wo du deutsch lernst? Präteritum vs. Perfekt ist ein bißchen eine Nord- Süd-Geschichte. Südlich der Mainlinie wird in der Umgangssprache fast nur Perfekt verwendet (weil die dortigen Dialekte gar kein Präteritum kennen)

Comment: Der Wikipedia-Artikel zum [Präteritum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4teritum) erklärt die Situation in Deutschland ganz gut. Kurz: Im Süden ist das Perfekt als Vergangenheitsform üblich, im Norden Deutschlands breitet sich das Perfekt über die Massenmedien aus und das dort bislang gebräuchliche Präteritum schwindet. Mündliche Erzählungen sind von der Einleitung abgesehen üblicherweise im Präsens ("Gestern war ich beim Arzt. Ich geh da rein und der sagt zu mir ..."), auch Mischformen sind häufig ("Der nimmt den größten Bohrer. Mir ist echt schwindlig geworden!").

Comment: @tofro  Ein Lehrer kommt aus Bremen, aber wohnt außerhalb Deutschlands seit Jahrzehnten.  Die andere Lehrerin kommt aus Hamburg, aber auch sie befindet sich außerhalb Deutschlands seit langer Zeit.

Comment: @Cerulean Das ist witzig, denn grade das sind Gegenden, wo in D das Präteritum eher verbreitet ist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die deutsche Sprache (und, vor allem, die deutsche Umgangssprache) ist i.A. sehr lässig – meiner Ansicht nach lässiger als andere Sprachen in Mitteleuropa – im Umgang mit den Zeitformen: In der Umgangssprache gibt es eine Zeitform für die Gegenwart und eine für die Vergangenheit und möglicherweise eine für die Zukunft, aber das ist schon gehobene Sprache. Oft verwenden wir auch das Präsens für das Futur oder gehen sehr nachlässig mit Vor- und Nachzeitigkeiten um und machen nur aus dem Zusammenhang klar, was wir meinen. Das Deutsche bietet so viele Möglichkeiten, komplexe zeitliche Zusammenhänge mit anderen Mitteln als dem Tempus zum Ausdruck zu bringen (z.B. mit Temporaladverbien), dass das i.A. akzeptiert und „für normal“ gehalten wird.

Für die Vergangenheitszeitform kann der Sprecher zwischen Perfekt und Präteritum relativ frei wählen – auch wenn das im Grammatikbuch anders steht. Nun ist es so, dass praktisch alle deutschen Dialekte südlich der Mainlinie im deutschen Sprachraum (also praktisch die Hälfte) gar kein Präteritum kennen. Da der Dialekt beim Spracherwerb typischerweise das ist, mit dem Menschen zuerst in Berührung kommen, bedeutet(-e – Dialektsprache wird erwiesenermaßen zunehmend weniger) das, dass Muttersprachler südlich der Mainlinie erst in der Grundschule mit dem Präteritum aktiv in Kontakt kommen und diese Zeitform eher wie in einer „ersten Fremdsprache“ erlernen. Sie werden wahrscheinlich diese Zeitform im späteren Leben eher in geringerem Maß (meine Erfahrung zeigt: in der Regel gar nicht) als Norddeutsche, deren Regiolekt das Präteritum kennt, verwenden. Aus diesem Grund gibt es ein gewisses Nord-/Süd-Gefälle bei der Verwendung von Präteritum gegenüber dem Perfekt, und es mag sein, dass deinen Lehrern aufgrund ihrer regionalen Prägung das besonders auffällt. Trotzdem im Norden das Präteritum verbreiteter ist, weichen auch Muttersprachler von dort bei eher komplexen Präteritumsbildungen oft (und immer öfter) auf das Perfekt aus, wahrscheinlich ganz einfach, weil die Partizipbildung – und damit das Perfekt – von Verben im Deutschen wesentlich regelmäßiger<sup>*</sup> ist als das Präteritum und damit die Möglichkeit, Fehler zu machen (oder der Denkaufwand, es richtig zu machen...), geringer.

Die deutsche Grammatik kennt an sich relativ klare Regeln (die du zu kennen scheinst), wann Präteritum und wann Perfekt zum Einsatz kommen soll – nur hält sich oft keiner dran. Das mag auch ein bisschen mit dem Sprachumgang zu tun haben: Wer viele Texte verfasst, wer viel liest und in höherem Maß mit geschriebener Sprache umgeht, mag das Präteritum eher gewohnt sein und es dann auch eher aktiv verwenden. Die Verwendung des Präteritums kann daher, wie immer wenn ein Sprecher alle, auch die weniger gängigen, Möglichkeiten der Sprache ausschöpft, als „gehoben“ oder sogar „geschraubt“ aufgefasst werden. Es scheint ein bisschen so zu sein, dass deine Lehrer dich kritisieren, dass du *zu gut* die Regeln befolgst (Ich hätte da eine geteilte Auffassung dazu …).

Kurz und gut: Es gibt im Deutschen, zumindest für gesprochene Sprache, **keine Regel** die sagen würde, dass du „nicht so oft das Präteritum verwenden“ sollst – nichts daran ist faktisch falsch, und wie du sicher schon gemerkt hast, wirst du auch verstanden, wenn du das tust. Es entspricht allerdings nicht dem gängigen Sprachgebrauch, d.h., wenn du irgendwann „perfektes“ (sic!) Deutsch sprechen willst, solltest du tatsächlich eher öfter das Perfekt verwenden - das verringert durchaus auch den Lernaufwand, denn das ist ja der Grund, warum Muttersprachler es tun. (Ich persönlich sehe allerdings nicht, dass du das tun solltest, weil ich es eher symphatisch finde, wenn man einem Nicht-Muttersprachler, der perfekt mit den Tempora des Deutschen umgehen kann, auch anhört, dass es nicht seine Muttersprache ist.)

---

<sup>*</sup>Betrachtet man Verben wie „backen“, „bitten“, „fechten“ und „braten“, weiß man schnell, was ich meine. Viele Muttersprachler (und ich auch) müssen fürs Präteritum erstmal nachdenken, während das Partizip sofort gebildet ist.

Comment: Ein schöner zusammenhängender Text. Mal was anderes hier. ;-) (+1)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Das war mein Wort zum Sonntag...

Comment: +1. Aber bitten ist da eher ein schlechtes Beispiel... weil unregelmäßig :) bitten - bat - gebeten

Comment: @planetmaker Vielleicht hast du recht, aber auch "unregelmäßige" Verben haben im Deutschen bei der Partizipbildung eine gewisse Regelmäßigkeit - Im Präteritum vermisse ich die oft.

Comment: @tofro Danke!  Wie ich oben erwähnt habe, waren die, die mich kritisiert haben (bzw. mir geholfen haben), beide aus Nord-Deutschland.  Also ich weiß nicht der Grund, warum sie das sagten (gesagt haben :-) ).  Ich glaube dass, ihrer Meinung nach, das Präteritum beim Sprechen zu "formell" vorkommt, d.h., dass es ein bisschen gestelzt klingt.  Kann sein, wie du sagst, dass viel Lesen einem das Präteritum einprägt, das habe ich bei mir gemerkt.  Aber letztendlich möchte ich einfach beim Sprechn natürlich vorkommen.

Comment: Präteritum in der Umgangssprache klingt unnatürlich. Wenn du nicht wie die Gebrüder Grimm klingen möchtest, solltest du mündlich bevorzugt das Perfekt benutzen.

Answer (score 3):

Süddeutsche benutzen praktisch nie Präteritum als Ersatz für Perfekt.

Norddeutsche benutzen Präteritum als Ersatz für Perfekt nur für die Hilfsverben, die Modalverben, und ein paar sehr gebräuchliche Verben wie z.B. geben. Bei den letzteren kommt es aber auch auf den Kontext an:

- Es gab Erbsensuppe.

aber

- Micha hat mir die Schlüssel gegeben.

und nicht etwa

- <strike>Micha gab mir die Schlüssel.</strike>

So spricht keiner. Auch nicht im nördlichsten Norddeutschland.

Comment: Niemand benutzt Präteritum "als Ersatz für Perfekt".

Comment: Liebe Janka, auch in dieser Antwort stört mich wieder mal der Absolutismus. Zitat: „So spricht keiner. Auch nicht im nördlichen Norddeutschland.“ Einspruch, denn zum Beispiel spreche ich nicht selten genau so, zugegeben: häufiger als andere in meinem Alltag, was daran liegen mag, dass ich extrem viele Texte im Präteritum lese oder selber verfasse und dann beim Sprechen in dieser Zeitform bleibt. Aber ich bin auch nicht der einzige, und daher ist die Aussage falsch.