# Warum Perfekt anstelle von Präteritum und seit wann?

Tags: history, tense, past

Seit welcher Zeit und warum wird im ge­spro­chenen Deutsch lieber Per­fekt anstatt Präteritum benutzt, z.B. lieber `Ich habe gesehen` als `Ich sah`? Warum hat sich die kompliziertere Form eingebürgert?

Comment: Ich würde sagen, dass es sich durchgesetzt hat, weil es **nicht** die kompliziertere Form ist. Die Perfektbildung der einzelnen Verben unterscheidet sich kaum, wohingegen die Präteritumformen sehr unterschiedlich sind.
`Ich sah` ist dafür ein gutes Beispiel.

Comment: D.h. zu konjugieren wird als komplizierter erachtet als 4 Silben mehr zu sprechen?

Comment: Ja, bilde doch als Übung mal das Präteritum und Perfekt von `ableiten, backen, niesen und stecken`

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass einer der beiden Formen komplizierter ist. Wäre es so, würde die eine oder eben andere Form (fast) ganz aus dem Sprachgebrauch eliminiert. Aber dem ist nicht so. Beide sind durch aus häufig im Gebrauch. @hirse: Bei *niesen* ist das Perfekt schwerer: gießen ist gegossen, schießen ist geschossen, niesen (was sich gesprochen nicht unterscheidet) ist geniest. Bei *ableiten* ist das Perfekt **scheinbar** 'schwerer'. Bei *backen* das Präteritum (backte setzt sich neuerdings durch) und bei *stecken* sind beide 'normal einfach' (*stak* hab ich noch nie gehört im realen Gebrauch)

Comment: falkb, dich interessiert vllt dieser [Artikel](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/prateritum-imperfekt-perfekt.php). Deine Frage wird dort zwar nicht beantwortet, aber dennoch interessant.

Comment: @em1 ich muss ehrlich sagen, dass ich das mit dem niesen noch nicht mal gewusst hätte...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In großen Teilen des deutschen Sprachgebiets wird ein *-e* am Wortende regelmäßig ausgelassen (*Apokope*), man sagt also beispielsweise *ich fahr’* statt *ich fahre* oder *müd’* statt *müde*. Nur in einem relativ schmalen Streifen vom Emsland nach Brandenburg ist das *-e* in den Dialekten erhalten.

Wo die Apokope durchgeführt ist, fällt bei schwachen Verben in der dritten Person Singular – eine der häufigsten Formen – das Präteritum mit dem Präsens zusammen: *er sagt* – *er sagt’*, *sie schaut* – *sie schaut’*. Damit taugt das Präteritum nicht mehr dazu, klarzumachen, daß von der Vergangenheit und nicht der Gegenwart die Rede ist, und man muß ausweichen. Hierfür bietet sich das Perfekt als weiteres Vergangenheitstempus an.

Bei den starken Verben (*sie fährt* – *sie fuhr*) und in den anderen Personen (*ich sag’* – *ich sagt’*) stellt sich das Problem eigentlich nicht. In einem großen Gebiet im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums hat sich das Perfekt aber auch dafür durchgesetzt und das Präteritum weitgehend verdrängt. Die Linie, bis zu der das passiert, heißt *Präteritalgrenze* und verläuft grob etwas nördlich von Mosel und Main. Es ist, wie immer, keine ganz scharfe Grenze – je weiter im Norden, desto eher gibt es noch Reste vom Präteritum. Nach Süden hin hält sich am besten noch *war*, vermutlich weil es so häufig gebraucht wird und von den Präsensformen klar zu unterscheiden ist.

In die Umgangssprache nördlich der Präteritalgrenze hat sich die allgemeine Verwendung des Perfekts erst in der jüngeren Vergangenheit ausgebreitet, wahrscheinlich durch die Massenmedien, [wie auch Belles Lettres schreibt](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/prateritum-imperfekt-perfekt.php) (Link von Em1).

Das Thema gab es übrigens neulich schon einmal: [Präteritum of "sein" in Southern dialects](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7050/) Dort auch der Verweis auf den *dtv-Atlas zur deutschen Sprache*.

Comment: Also Belles Lettres erwähnt nicht deine Erklärung. Stattdessen steht da, der Süden hat es sich wahrscheinlich aus dem Lateinischen abgekuckt: "... *Ein Motiv für die Aufteilung zwischen Nord und Süd könnte im Lateinischen liegen. Dort ist das Perfekt das Tempus, in dem Vergangenes erzählt wird.* ..." OK, warum sie das getan haben, ist auch nicht erklärt. Vielleicht aus den Gründen, die du genannt hast...

Comment: @falkb: Ich habe auch nicht behauptet, daß Belles Lettres diese Erklärung gibt. Ich _habe_ behauptet, daß Belles Lettres die Ausbreitung nach Norden der jüngeren Vergangenheit und den Massenmedien zuschreibt, und das tut es: „Erst in den letz­ten Jahr­zehn­ten kol­li­dier­ten die beiden Sys­teme zum erstenmal durch die Mas­sen­kom­mu­ni­ka­tion. Das führte dazu, daß sich das Sys­tem des Sü­dens heu­te als Stan­dard durch­gesetzt hat.“

Comment: Ist der Verwechslungsgrund bezüglich der weggelassenen e-Endung im dtv-Atlas als Fakt oder Theorie aufgeführt?

Comment: @falkb: „… wird in der Regel als direkte Folge der Apokope des _e_ (vgl. S. 159) betrachtet.“

Comment: das Zitat aus dem dtv-Atlas lässt aber auch Interpretationsspielraum zu, ob sie das als Fakt oder Theorie meinen...

Comment: @falkb: Über die Ursachen von Sprachwandel kann man immer nur Theorien aufstellen, da man die Beteiligten nicht mehr fragen kann; und selbst wenn, sie die Änderungen im allgemeinen nicht bewußt beschlossen (oder überhaupt wahrgenommen) haben. Die Einschätzung im dtv-Atlas bedeutet: Es ist die Theorie, die die Mehrzahl der Forscher für die plausibelste hält, aber nicht die einzige.

Comment: Gut, das überzeugt mich fast vollständig. Ich lasse das Thema trotzdem noch eine Weile aktiv. Vielleicht war es aber auch einfach fromm, sich im Latein-Stil (gebildet wie der Pfarrer) auszudrücken? Immer wieder erstaunlich, dass solche Änderungen nicht notiert wurden. Weiß zufällig noch jemand, seit wann der Perfekt den Süden dominiert?

Comment: @falkb: Noch einmal der dtv-Atlas: „Dieser Schwund tritt in der geschriebenen Sprache im 15. Jh. zuerst auf.“ (Auch ein Grund, warum mich die Konfessionstheorie von Belles Lettres nicht so überzeugt. ;-)) Die Schriftsprache ist eher konservativ, daher dürfte die Entwicklung im Mündlichen schon etwas früher angefangen haben.

Answer (score 1):

Ich verwende Perfekt aus zwei persönlichen Vorlieben:

1. Die Verdeutlichung der Vergangenheit, da das Präteritum zu
   kurzfristig und teilweise unabgeschlossen klingt, ohne auf die
   ursprünglichen Aspekte der Nutzungsbedingungen zu achten. :)
2. Die Verlängerung durch ein zweites Verb gibt mir die hervorragende
   Möglichkeit, Nebensätze (vor allem Attributsätze) einzufügen.
   Umhüllte Nebensätze finde ich schöner als die angehängten, da der
   zweite Teil zum Thema des Satzes zurückführt und ein mögliches
   Abschweifen minimiert.

Comment: +1 für das Satzklammerargument

Comment: zu 1.) der Perfekt/Präteritum-Gebrauch im Deutschen hat aber nichts mit den Regeln zum entsprechenden Gebrauch im Englischen zu tun

Comment: Die Frage fragt explizit nicht nach den persönlichen Vorlieben, und eine kleine Anzahl von Leuten die aus diesen Gründen lieber das Perfekt verwendet, macht noch keinen Sprachgebrauch von ca. 100 Millionen Menschen.

Answer (score 0):

Das lässt sich einfach erklären. Im Lateinischen wird das Perfekt, nicht das Präteritum als Erzähltempus verwendet und durch das erneute Aufleben der lateinischen Sprache, gerade in unserem Sprachraum gegen 1513 durch die Bibelübersetzung setzte sich mehr und mehr das Perfekt durch. Ich benutze heute aber immer noch lieber das Präteritum.

Comment: Ich glaube, du machst es dir zu einfach. Auch in England war das Lateinische (und das Französische) allgegenwärtig, und wurde erst durch Bibelübersetzungen vollständig verdrängt, trotzdem hat sich dort nie das Perfekt durchgesetzt, da es im Englischen eine Bedeutungsunterscheidung gibt. Demgegenüber hat das Französische drei Vergangenheitsformen, von denen zwei Bedeutungsgleich ist: ein zusammengesetztes Perfekt und ein *Passé simple*, die neben einer Imperfektform existieren. Das Passé simple müsste sich direkt aus dem Lateinischen ableiten lassen, warum hat es sich dann nicht durchgesetzt? …

Comment: … Luther hat in seiner Bibelübersetzung auch explizit »dem Volk aufs Maul geschaut«, und hätte demnach auf keinen Fall eine ungewohntere Form gewählt, nur um Analogie zum Lateinischen aufrechtzuerhalten. Zudem wimmelt es in der Bibel nur so von Präterita: »Und der Herr sprach« »Und es ward Abend, und es ward Morgen«, »Aber Adam antwortete und sprach«. Das lässt nur den Schluss zu, dass in Mittelthüringen im 16. Jahrhundert viel mehr Präteritum benutzt wurde als heute. Insgesamt: Quellen bitte, bis dahin –1.