# What is the difference between 'ist gewesen' and 'war'

Tags: tense, perfect-tense, past

My German tandem partner told me that a friend of him was for a half year in Brazil. He said:

> Er ist ein halbes Jahr in Brasilien gewesen

What's the difference to

> Er war ein halbes Jahr in Brasilien

Comment: And also related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5055/usage-of-perfekt-and-pr%c3%a4teritum-in-the-spoken-language and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/warum-perfekt-anstelle-von-pr%c3%a4teritum-und-seit-wann

Comment: In official German language (literature or newspapers) there are rules when to use which of the two forms. However for most native speakers in "everyday language" it depends on the region they come from if they prefer "war" or "ist gewesen". There is no difference in the meaning.

Comment: @wogsland: While you are encouraged to participate in killing the grammar tag, please adhere to the guidelines imposed [here](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1210/2594). In particular removing the grammar tag should rarely be the only change to a question. Also, please do not flood the suggested-edit queue.

Answer (score -2):

They are different tenses:

- **Perfekt**: *Er ist gewesen*
- **Präteritum**: *Er war*

Some people say, that **Präteritum** is the one which is more in the past but I think **that's wrong**. Both tenses can be used for the same thing.

However I guess most Germans would prefer the Perfekt because it's easier.

Comment: Perfekt is easier?

Comment: Well it's one word less...

Comment: How is Perfekt one word less than Präteritum?