# Difference between Austrian and German

Tags: grammar, standard-german, austrian

Die Österreicher haben im Vergleich zu uns (Hoch-)Deutschen ein paar lustige Wörter und eine etwas andere (wie ich finde netter klingende) Aussprache (wobei das natürlich von Person zu Person variiert); Gibt es aber auch Unterschiede in der Grammatik?

---

Besides slightly different vocabulary and pronunciation, are there differences in Austrian and German grammar?

Comment: Bitte nicht "Hochdeutsch" mit "deutschem Deutsch" verwechseln. "Hochdeutsch" gibt es in der deutschen, der österreichischen und der schweizerischen Varietät; dazu gibt es auch regional deutlicher unterschiedene umgangssprachliche Wendungen.

Comment: @wolfgang: Ich bezog mich auf österreichisches Hochdeutsch zu deutschem Hochdeutsch, ja. Beispielsweise ist österreichisches Deutsch dem Bayrischen recht ähnlich. Das "(Hoch-)" sollte also zur Abgrenzung zu deutschen Dialekten/Akzenten dienen, nicht zur Abgrenzung zum Österreichischen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia has quite nice articles about both [German](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_language) and [Austrian German](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austrian_German):

> Much like the relationship between British English and American English, the Austrian and German varieties differ in minor respects (e.g., **spelling**, **word usage** and **grammar**).

Also, it adds a part about differences between them in grammar:

> - In Austria, as in the German-speaking parts of Switzerland and in
>     southern Germany, verbs that express a state tend to use `sein` as the
>     auxiliary verb in the perfect, as well as verbs of movement. Verbs
>     which fall into this category include `sitzen` (to sit), `liegen` (to
>     lie) and, in parts of Carinthia, `schlafen` (to sleep). Therefore the
>     perfect of these verbs would be `ich bin gesessen`, `ich bin gelegen` and
>     `ich bin geschlafen` respectively (note: `ich bin geschlafen` is a very
>     rare form, usually you will hear `ich habe geschlafen`; but 
>     `ich bin eingeschlafen` [I fell asleep] is quite normal).
> - In the variant of German that is spoken in Germany, the words `stehen`
>     (to stand) and `gestehen` (to confess) are identical in the present
>     perfect: `habe gestanden`. The Austrian variant avoids this potential
>     ambiguity (`bin gestanden` from `stehen`, `habe gestanden` from `gestehen`).
> - Also, the preterite (simple past) is very rarely used in Austria,
>     especially in the spoken language, except for some modal verbs (`ich sollte, ich wollte`).

Comment: I'd say that the last point is valid for Germany, too. In the _spoken_ language, the simple past is rarely used, except for some modal verbs. (I don't know anything about differences in the _written_ language.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: [This question](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-to-use-perfekt-and-prateritum) says it's not so, at least in written language.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I know that the simple past is _the_ choice in the written language in Germany. What I meant is that I don't know anything about differences between Germany and Austria in this matter.

Comment: I lived in Switzerland for a few years. In spoken dialects, I rarely heard (never?) the simple past. But when a Swiss would shift from dialect to High German, they would sometimes use the simple past (but not often). Here is my hypothesis on that: High German is primarily a written language in Switzerland. When the Swiss shift from a dialect into High German, they might be imagining how they would express themselves in writing. [Alt hypothesis: if northern Germans use the simple past more frequently than the Swiss when speaking, the Swiss could be imagining a northern speaker.]

Comment: @HendrikVogt the further North you get, the more common the preterite tends to get.

Comment: Second point is blatantly wrong. "bin/bist/seid gestanden" is the normal form in Alemannic regions, i.e. outside Austria. "I bin in d'r Schlange g'schtanda." "Bisch' wieder da ganze Dog am Fenschter g'schtanda?"

Answer (score 6):

Erstmal: Die mit den lustigen Wörtern seid Ihr Deutschen, nicht wir Österreicher. Uns Österreichern würde nämlich nicht einfallen, so seltsam klingende Wörter wie »Quark« oder »Eisbein« zu sagen.
Aber ernsthaft: Ich denke, das Wort, das du eigentlich meist ist nicht »lustig« sondern »anders«. Österreichisches Deutsch ist nicht lustiger oder ernster als Deutsches Deutsch, oder irgend eine andere Sprache.

Ich möchte vorausschicken, dass - vor allem in Bezug auf die Umgangssprache - vieles, was hier über Österreich gesagt wird, auch auf südliche Regionen Deutschlands zutrifft.

Es gibt aber auch offizielle Grammatikregeln, die nur für die Hochsprache »Österreichisches Deutsch«, nicht aber für die Hochsprache »Deutsches Deutsch« gelten (und umgekehrt). Diese Regeln gelten für verschiedene Varietäten der Deutschen Sprache, aber diese Regeln schreiben nicht vor, in welcher geographischen Region diese Varietäten tatsächlich verwendet werden.

Man wird daher auch in Wien Menschen antreffen, die beispielsweise so etwas sagen:

> Ich habe **Aprikosenkonfitüre** gemacht als ich **im** Urlaub war.

obwohl das in Österreichischem Deutsch so lauten würde:

> Ich habe **Marillenmarmelade** gemacht als ich **auf** Urlaub war.

---

**Ja, die Grammatik des Österreichischen Deutsch unterscheidet sich von der Grammatik des Deutschen Deutsch und von der des Schweizerischen Deutsch.**

Da ich vom Schweizerischen Deutsch keine Ahnung habe, vergleiche ich hier aber nur Österreichisches und Deutsches Deutsch.

Der auffälligste Unterschied betrifft die Zeiten. Die werden im Österreichischen Deutsch nicht nur anders verwendet als im Deutschen Deutsch, sondern sie heißen (im Schulunterricht) auch anders:

> **Präteritum**
>   Ich schlief. Wir redeten. Hans arbeitete.

In Deutschland hat diese Zeitform gleich drei verschiedene deutsche Namen: »*unvollendete Vergangenheit*«, »*Nachvergangenheit*« und »*1. Vergangenheit*«. In (nicht »an«!) Österreichischen Schulen wird gelehrt, dass der deutsche Name des Präteritums »*Mitvergangenheit*« ist.

In der geschriebenen Sprache wird das Präteritum in beiden Ländern benutzt um Ereignisse zu schildern, die in der Vergangenheit geschehen sind und abgeschlossen sind. Die Handlungen reichen also nicht bis in die Gegenwart.

Der Grund dafür ist aber hauptsächlich, dass man auch in Österreich als geschriebene Sprache häufig Deutsches Deutsch (oder eine deutsch-österreichische Mischform) benutzt. Vor allem Bücher kann man nicht in Österreichischem Deutsch schrieben, weil man sie in Deutschland nicht verkaufen könnte. (Ausnahmen gibt es, aber Autoren wie Wolf Haas verkaufen im 8,5-Millionen-Einwohnerland Österreich auch deutlich mehr Bücher als in Deutschland mit 81 Millionen potentiellen Kunden)

In Deutschland (vor allem im Norden) wird auch in der gesprochenen Alltagssprache das Präteritum verwendet um von abgeschlossenen Ereignissen zu berichten: »Vor einem Jahr schnitt ich mir in den Finger. (Die Wunde ist längst verheilt)«

In Österreich (und Teilen Bayerns) wird diese Zeitform in der Alltagssprache kaum verwendet. Als ich als Kind in die Schule kam, kannte ich diese Zeitform gar nicht, den außer bei Sätzen mit »*war*« als Verb (»Ich war im Bad«, »Thomas war krank«) wird die Mitvergangenheit im Alltag nur selten verwendet.

> **Perfekt**
>   Ich habe geschlafen. Wir haben geredet. Hans hat gearbeitet.

Offizielle Namen in Deutschland: »vollendete Gegenwart«, »Vorgegenwart« und »2. Vergangenheit«.
Offizieller Name in Österreich: »Vergangenheit.«

Am Namen erkennt man schon den wesentlichen Unterschied: In Deutschland wird das als eine Form der Gegenwart verstanden, die sich aus einem vergangenem Ereignis ergibt. In Österreich ist es schlichtweg die Standard-Form um etwas auszudrücken das in der Vergangenheit stattgefunden hat: »Vor einem Jahr habe ich mir in den Finger geschnitten. (Die Wunde ist längst verheilt)«. Ein Bezug zur Gegenwart ist nicht erforderlich, stört aber auch nicht.

In Österreich wird daher alles, was in der Vergangenheit passiert ist (und nicht zwingend den Pluquamperfekt erfordert) in der Zeitform »Vergangenheit« ausgedrückt.

Beispiel:

> In Deutschland:
>   Ich kann mich noch an deinen fünften Geburtstag erinnern. Erst schien die Sonne vom Himmel, dann zog ein Sturm auf, und plötzlich begann es zu regnen und wir liefen dann alle ins Haus. Das ist jetzt 30 Jahre her, und das Haus steht auch nicht mehr.
>
> In Österreich:
>   Ich kann mich noch an deinen fünften Geburtstag erinnern. Am Anfang hat noch die Sonne gescheint, dann ist ein Sturm aufgezogen, und plötzlich hat es angefangen zu regnen, und wir sind alle ins Haus gelaufen. Das ist jetzt 30 Jahre her, und das Haus steht auch nicht mehr.

Statt »gescheint« ist auch »geschienen« erlaubt, aber gerade in der gesprochenen Sprache eher ungebräuchlich.

> Plusquamperfekt

Die Zeitform »Plusquamperfekt« hat in beiden Ländern denselben Namen (»Vorvergangenheit«) und wird auch gleich verwendet. Jedoch habe ich den Eindruck, dass sie in Österreich häufig durch andere Formulierungen vermieden wird.

---

Der Partizip Perfekt einiger Verben enden in Österreich auf -en statt auf -et oder -t:

> D: Der Fernseher ist eingeschalt**et**.
>   Ö: Der Fernseher ist eingeschalt**en**.
>
> D: Die Suppe ist versalz**t**.
>   Ö: Die Suppe ist versalz**en**.

Es gibt aber auch den umgekehrten Fall:

> D: Der Insasse ist abgehau**en**.
>   Ö: Der Insasse ist abgehau**t**.

Auch in einer unregelmäßigen Variante:

> D: Inge hat mir zugew**i**nk**t**.
>   Ö: Inge hat mir zugew**u**nk**en**.

Auch hier gilt: Es gibt auch Regionen in Deutschland, in denen die Österreich-Variante verwendet wird, und die deutsche Version ist auch in Österreich erlaubt, wird hier aber selten bis gar nicht verwendet (hängt vom Wort und von der Region ab)

---

***Haben* und *sein***

Der Satz »Karl hat gesessen« bedeutet in Österreich unzweifelhaft, dass Karl im Gefängnis war. Will man aussagen, dass er sich in sitzender Haltung auf einem Möbelstück aufgehalten hat, sagt man in Österreich:

> Karl ist auf dem Sessel gesessen. (nicht: *hat auf dem Stuhl gesessen*)

Ebenso:

> Susi ist im Bett gelegen. (nicht: *hat im Bett gelegen*)
>   Martin ist hier gestanden. (nicht: *hat hier gestanden*)

Die hier genannten *hat*-Varianten werden in Österreich als falsch empfunden.

Kurzer Exkurs:
»Sessel« ist in Deutschland ein gepolstertes Sitzmöbel mit Armlehnen für eine Person. In Österreich ist »Sessel« jedoch der Oberbegriff für alle Ein-Personen-Sitzmöbel. Ein schlichter Holzstuhl ohne Lehne und mit harter Sitzfläche ist in Österreich nicht nur ein Stuhl, sondern auch ein Sessel. Der typische bequeme Sessel, den man als »Sofa für eine Person« bezeichnen könnte, heißt in Österreich »Fauteuil«.

---

Viele Präpositionen sind auch unterschiedlich:

> D: Dieser Händler bietet dieses Buch **für** 9,90 Euro an.
>   Ö: Dieser Händler bietet dieses Buch **um** 9,90 Euro an.
>
> D: Leon wird jetzt sechs, bald darf er **zur** Schule gehen.
>   Ö: Leon wird jetzt sechs, bald darf er **in die** Schule gehen.
>
> D: Wo ist Herr Müller? - Er ist **im** Urlaub.
>   Ö: Wo ist Herr Müller? - Er ist **auf** Urlaub.

---

Viele Hauptwörter haben in Österreich ein anderes Geschlecht als in Deutschland:

> D: die Cola, Ö: das Cola
>   D: das Spray, Ö: der Spray
>   D: der Joghurt, Ö: das Joghurt
>   D: der Keks, Ö: das Keks
>   D: die Akte, Ö: der Akt

---

Dieser Abschnitt betrifft zwar die Grammatik-Regeln nicht direkt, passt aber dennoch zum Thema:

Einige Grammatik-Begriffe heißen in Österreich auch anders:

- **Verb** in D: »Tätigkeitswort«, in Ö: »Zeitwort«
- **,** in D: »Komma«, in Ö: »Beistrich« (nicht jedoch wenn es als Dezimaltrennzeichen in Zahlen auftritt)
- **!** In D: »Ausrufezeichen«, in Ö: »Rufzeichen«

Anmerkung 1: *Zeitwort*, *Beistrich* und *Rufzeichen* (und einige weitere Begriffe) sind auch in einigen Gegenden Deutschlands in Gebrauch, diese Begriffe werden aber nicht im Unterricht an Deutschen Schulen gelehrt. Der behördlich vorgegebene Lehrplan österreichischer Schulen enthält aber genau diese Wörter, und sieht auch vor, dass sie im Unterricht gelehrt werden.

Anmerkung 2: Der unterschiedliche Lehrplan hat auch eine Auswirkung auf die Mathematik. Die Geradengleichung lautet in Deutschland: »y = mx + n«, in Österreichs Mathe-Lehrbüchern steht aber: »y = kx + d«

Comment: Ich hab in Bayern *y* = *m x* + *t* gelernt … Vermutlich ist da jedes deutsche Bundesland anderst.

Comment: And of course in the English-speaking world, y=mx+b. Great article, thanks Hubert. (Now I wonder what the equation of a straight line looks like in French?

Comment: Sehr, sehr viel von dem, was du hier als "trennende Unterschiede" zwischen deutschem und österreichischem Deutsch aufzählst, sind keine, sondern generische Unterschiede im Nord-Süd-Gefälle der deutschen Sprache (das ab ca. der Mainlinie steil abfällt...)

Answer (score 4):

Folgende Unterschiede fallen mir noch ein:

- *am* als Verkürzung von sowohl *an dem* als auch *auf dem*: "Die Speisen stehen am Tisch".
- Wenn man etwas *um* 10 Euro kauft, so sind das exakt 10 Euro. Offenbar können (Nord-)Deutsche dies als ungefähren Ausdruck interpretieren (dies wäre allerdings *um die* 10 Euro).
- anderes Genus für diverse Dinge: "*das* E-Mail", "*das* Joghurt", "*das* Cola", "*der* Akt" (statt *die* Akte)

Comment: Ich denke *am* als Abkürzung von *an dem* gilt für beide, oder irre ich mich?

Comment: Ja, *am* kann im gesamten deutschen Sprachrum *an dem* bedeuten. In Österreich kann *am* allerdings auch *auf dem* bedeuten.

Answer (score 0):

The word *Hochdeutsch* is important in your question, since grammar also differs within German dialicts. For example we in Hesse have what's called the "Hessischer Genetiv" in a sentence like `Das ist dem Alex sein Auto`, which clearly differs from the correct Hochdeutsch.

So, concerning German and Austrian, it depends on what you compare, since the dialect from Bavaria is for example much closer to Austrian than others. It reminds me of a situation where I followed a conversation between someone from close to the Austrian border and someone from Salzburg area and I was not able to tell them apart.

Comment: Ich habe das als Unterschied im Hochdeutschen aufgefasst. Bairisch, wie das alle Österreicher mit Ausnahme der Vorarlberger spechen, hat eine eigene Grammatik.

Answer (score 0):

Ja, es gibt im österreichischen Deutsch noch ein paar Besonderheiten, vor allem bei zusammengesetzten Wörtern und Fugenlauten (Schweinebraten vs. Schweinsbraten), und auch die Verwendung von "sein" statt "haben" für Verben der Bewegung und Ähnliches: ich bin (statt: habe) gesessen, gestanden, gelegen.

Schließlich ist auch noch die Vergangenheit, jedenfalls in der gesprochenen Sprache, viel üblicher als die Mitvergangenheit (Präteritum).

Answer (score 0):

In Austrian you often find, rather than `-lein` and `chen`, for the diminutive the the

> -l, -rl, -erl, -ei

endings.

Example: Vogerl (Österreichisch) vs. Vögelchen