# The role of "sein" with a verb in "infinitive"

Tags: word-choice, verb-usage

I’ve recently come across a sentence:

> Einmal war ich nach einer Party um zwei Uhr morgens Döner essen mit Jamaal, einem syrischen Freund.

What I didn’t understand is what *war* is doing here? When I translated the sentence with Google Translate, its translation was:

> Once, after a party at two o’clock in the morning, I was eating kebabs with Jamaal, a Syrian friend.

So is the verb *to be* sometimes used to create a continuous form in a sentence? But I was under the impression that it’s not necessary; we just use the simple tense to make a continuous sentence.

Comment: The construction is discussed in detail here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15529/absentiv-oder-doch-was-anderes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Absentiv" oder doch was anderes](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15529/absentiv-oder-doch-was-anderes)

Comment: Not a dupe because the other question is in German.

Comment: You're right, I didn't even notice.

Comment: @DavidVogt Unfortunately, I don't understand instructions in German

Answer (score 4, accepted):

German knows 3 general possibilities of expressing the English continuous tense:

- by adding temporal adjective markers, e.g. "ich esse gerade"
- by
     using sein + am/beim + Infinitiv  (aka Verlaufsform, probably the closest option to the English *continous tense*)

  - **by using sein + Infinitiv** (aka [Absentive (wiki:en)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absentive_aspect)), which also happens to be your case.

The latter possibility is often used when expressing a state of being busy, often with a local subtone to it (not being able to "be there"),  e.g.

> -Wo warst du denn?
>   -Ich war einkaufen.

An example of the second possibility: (nobody's absent or busy, just expressing a state)

> Mann, ich bin am Verhungern!  - Hey, I'm starving!

It is debated whether there the 3d possibility deserves the name "absentive", but we can still use this as a shorcut for understanding this complicated business.

To your question, if it's necessary or not: unlike with English, you can perfectly do without these constructions, they are used predominantly in colloquial speech and can be painlessly substituted by saying e.g. "Ich kaufe **gerade** ein, in einer Stunde bin ich wieder da".

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/18491/9739 related