# wählen gehen, but it is with sein

Tags: verb, idiom, infinitive

I came across the following sentence:

> 87 Prozent der unter 25-Jährigen waren nicht wählen - ein historischer Negativrekord.

What does *waren nicht wählen* mean? Does *wählen sein* exist as a phrasal verb? Shouldn't it have been *gingen nicht wählen* instead?

Here's the source: https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/frankreich-regionalwahlen-korri-101.html

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54622/the-role-of-sein-with-a-verb-in-infinitive

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine

> Ich ging wählen.

as well as

> Ich war wählen.

With both constructions, the location were the action takes place comes into play - in this example, the polling station. With "gehen", the movement to the location is emphasized a little more, with "sein", the stay at the location is emphasized a little more. But that doesn't give a big difference in meaning.

Especially the construction of "sein" plus infinitive verb is typically used for actions that are bound to a specific location, or typically take place at a specific location. You might consider

> Ich war wählen.

as a bit of a shortened

> Ich war im Wahllokal und habe dort gewählt.

or

> Ich war an dem Ort, wo man wählt (und habe dort das getan, was man dort eben tut).

The same principle can be used with a lot of verbs, for example

> Ich war einkaufen. (typically done at a grocery store or the like)

> Ich war reiten. (typically done at a riding hall or similar)

> Ich war schwimmen. (not typically done in your living room ;) )

When used in past tense, this construction has the connotation of a finished action: "Ich war einkaufen" implies that I left home, went to the store, did my shopping and went back again.

It can also be used in present tense. Then, it has a subtext of business or occupation. "Ich bin (gerade) einkaufen" often implies something like "... deshalb kann ich leider gerade nicht um Dein Anliegen kümmern."

Answer (score 0):

Your are right, that *gehen* + infinitive is the standardized pattern, for which numerous other examples exist:

- einkaufen gehen
- Zimmer aufräumen gehen
- Zähneputzen gehen

This works for active mood only.

The interesting part is, that this pattern is used for indicating a future activitity only. As soon as a you refer to a currently ongoing event, there is no way to form it with *gehen*, it needs to be replaced by *sein* as in

> Ich bin gerade einkaufen. (or less colloquially: "Ich bin gerade beim Einkaufen.")

When the event slides to the past, *sein* keeps stuck, even if *gingen* does not seem to be wrong, but its not used frequently.

> Ich war einkaufen, wählen, mein Zimmer aufräumen, die Steuererklärung abgeben.

Comment: On passive constructs: "Ich war haareschneiden" is a nice one to wrap your head around.