Vergangenheitsform sein + Verb in Infinitform
I had Google translate the following three short sentences into german.

I go hiking. => Ich gehe wandern.
I have gone hiking. => Ich bin wandern gegangen.
I went hiking. => Ich war wandern.
We went hiking. => Wir waren wandern.

The first one is simply Infinitiv mit "gehen", the second one is Perfekt mit "sein".
However, I am confused with the structures of the third and fourth sentences. It seems like Vergangenheitsform sein + Verb in Infinitform. I couldn't find anything relating to this structure in my grammar book (up to B1). Could some shed a light on it?

The construction in your ex. 3 and 4 is called "absentive", see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absentive_aspect. A nice explanation in German is https://blog.leo.org/2009/09/13/wo-bist-du-%E2%80%93-ich-bin-einkaufen/
In short, the meaning of "ich bin V(infinitive)" is "I am off, doing V". Maybe the construction with "gehen" suggests something similar (walking away from here?), but it is not as clear.
I guess the switch seen in the translations has to do with the use of the simple past (Präteritum) in German, which is often felt to belong to the level of written language for full verbs (esp. in southern Germany). So a construction which only has the auxiliary "war" in the past tense form may sound more colloquial and in line with the style of the first examples. Just guessing...
With automatic translation, yon never know what may happen, I am not sure everything you get always has a good reason. For example, it is often not correct to assume that an English perfect needs a translation with a German perfect, and likewise for the simple past forms: the use and meaning of the tenses are not parallel in a number of respects.

Thank you for reply. This is the original sentence "Einmal war ich nach einer Party um zwei Uhr morgens Döner essen – mit Jamaal. Wir haben zwei Döner bestellt. Der Dönermann sagte zu Jamaal etwas auf Arabisch...." So, it may be translated as "Once, after a party at 2 am, I was having (or had ?) a Doner with Jamaal.... ".  Kind of simple past or past progressive. "Was having" sounds better in English since they were eating when Donnermann asked a question.

According to the "absentiv" logic it could mean "we were absent from home to eat Doner outside". But still strange construction. Specifically for a case when you are absent. Never seen in any grammar book of German.

@fade2black don't focus on any "absent" aspect of a construct like "Ich bin wandern". It's simply a form to express an activity in progress (here 'wandern'). It's also used in situations, like, you call, and I answer "Kann ich zurückrufen? Ich bin gerade am kochen" (Can I call back? I'm right now cooking / preparing food)

@planetmaker Thanks, got you. In this case it is something like present progressive. So the bottom line, it may correspond for various grammar constructs in English depending on the context and situation.

For the difference to the progressive see the disc in the blog entry that I referred to https://blog.leo.org/2009/09/13/wo-bist-du-%e2%80%93-ich-bin-einkaufen/#comment-106061

Funnily enough, the example with Jamaal was used to raise the question before, see https://german.stackexchange.com/q/54622.
