# Wann benutzt man Perfekt, wann Präteritum?

Tags: perfect-tense, preterite

Jetzt lerne ich B1 in Deutsch. Meine Professorin hat uns nie gesagt, wann man das Präteritum und wann das Perfekt benutzt. Wo liegt der Unterschied?

Comment: Willkommen! Vielleicht findest Du, was Du suchst, in den Antworten auf http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/246/ and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5055/. Falls nicht, dann versuche bitte, Deine Frage zu präzisieren, da sie ansonsten wahrscheinlich als Duplikat geschlossen wird.